# Force google account chooser

Tags: google-oauth

Is there is a way I can force the **google account chooser** to appear even if the user is logged in just with one account.

I have tried by redirecting to this URL:

```
https://accounts.google.com/AccountChooser?service=lso&continue=[authorizeurl]
```

and it seems to work, but I don't know if there are any other conditions in which it might fail.

[image]

Answer (score 110, accepted):

The following parameter is supported in OAuth2 authorization URLs:

`prompt`

Currently it can have values `none`, `select_account`, and `consent`.

- none: Will cause Google to not show any UI, and therefore fail if user needs to login, or select an account in case of multi-login, or consent if first approval. It can be run in an invisible i-frame to obtain a token from previously authorized users before you decide, for instance, to render an authorization button.
- consent: Will force the approval page to be displayed even if the user has previously authorized your application. May be useful in a few corner cases, for instance if you lost the refresh_token for the user, as Google only issues refresh_tokens on explicit consent action.
- select_account: Will cause the account selector to display, even if there's a single logged-in user, just as you asked.

`select_account` can be combined with `consent`, as in:

`prompt=select_account consent`

Comment: Is 'approval_prompt=force' the same than 'prompt=consent'? Thanks

Comment: Yes, but unlike prompt=consent it can't be combined with the option for 'select_account'. Use 'prompt' instead if writing new code now.

Comment: Is there a way to force login with gmail accounts (like hd=gmail.com)?

Comment: @woloski, yes, hd=default should restrict to gmail accounts

Comment: I get select_account screen but it has no remove button. How do i remove an account if i have to ?

Comment: Google Documentation and Options/Parameters
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#formingtheurl

Comment: prompt=select_account+consent does not work, you'll want to use prompt=select_account consent     ------ docs: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenIDConnect

Comment: `select_account+consent` is probably the URL encoded value. I think the answer should show a space delimited string instead, as documented.

Comment: If you are following the latest tutorial at https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in#specify_your_apps_client_id you can also add it to your button generation div.     <div class="g-signin2" data-width="300" data-height="50" data-longtitle="true" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-theme="dark" data-prompt="select_account"></div>

Comment: This does NOT require the user to authenticate again. There is no password prompt and any person can click on the user account and authorize. How the hell is this secure on a public computer? Can anyone please tell me how I force the user to submit his password again when signing in after he signed out?

Comment: @HugoCox Well, oauth2 is not about authentication, it's about authorization. You have no way to force google to require their users to login again. You can only require users to consent, or choose account. It's on Google to require authentication if user is not authenticated, you can only control authorization since your client is relying party not token issuer. Hope it clears it a little bit.

Comment: here is link to see the full api, for javascript:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow

Answer (score 13):

Also, you can add "prompt" parameter in HTML tags as data-prompt="select_account":

```
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-prompt="select_account">
```

and it will force account chooser every time, even if you are logged in with only one account

Comment: Not working for me, `<div class="g-signin2" data-scope="profile email" data-width="298" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-prompt="select_account" ></div>` but onSignIn still called every time

Comment: @BenjaminPoignant Your problem (success handler instantly called on page load) is slightly different to the one this question is about (although your confusion is understandable). As https://stackoverflow.com/a/15503280/1709587 notes, you need to use `gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut();` to sign the user out of your app. *This* question is about how, having done that, to ensure that when the user clicks the login button again they get a chance to choose which Google account to sign in as, rather than instantly using their current Google account as soon as the sign-in button is clicked.

Answer (score 13):

Some people may end up here looking for an answer about how to do this in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.

We were able to accomplish it via the following code in the Startup.ConfigureServices method:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
  .AddGoogle(options =>
  {
      options.ClientId = configHelper.GoogleOAuthClientID;
      options.ClientSecret = configHelper.GoogleOAuthSecret;
      options.CallbackPath = "/signin-google";
      options.AuthorizationEndpoint = string.Concat(options.AuthorizationEndpoint, "?prompt=select_account");
  });
```

Answer (score 4):

For **google api php client** (https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) you manage to do that as following:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApprovalPrompt("force");
$client->createAuthUrl();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `gapi` than just add `prompt: 'select_account'`
Example:

```
gapi.load('auth2', function () {
            gapi.auth2.init({
                client_id: "client_id.apps.googleusercontent.com",
                scope: "profile email", // this isn't required
                ux_mode: 'redirect',
                redirect_uri: 'https://www.example.com',
                prompt: 'select_account'
            }).then(function (auth2) {
                console.log("signed in: " + auth2.isSignedIn.get());
                x = auth2.isSignedIn.get();
                auth2.isSignedIn.listen(onSignIn);
                var button = document.querySelector('#signInButton');
                button.addEventListener('click', function () {
                    auth2.signIn();
                });
            });
        });
```