# Preventing automatic sign-in when using Google+ Sign-In

Tags: google-plus

I am in the process of integrating Google+ sign in with my site, which also lets users sign in with Twitter and Facebook. The sign in page of the site therefore has 3 buttons, one for each of the services.

The issue I am having is in the following scenario:

- user goes to the sign in page
- user signs in successfully with G+
- user signs out of my site (but the account is still associated with G+, signing out of the site does not disconnect the G+ account)
- user visits the sign in page again
- at this stage the Sign in with G+ button is rendered and automatically signs the user into the account associated with G+ without the user having to click the button

The problem is that on revisiting the sign in page, I want the user to have the option of signing in with another service, rather than automatically being signed in with G+. If the user wants to sign in with G+ then they can do so by clicking the button - the user will then be signed in automatically.

Is it possible to prevent this automatic sign in on button render? I can simulate it by using the `data-approvalprompt="force"` as an attribute on the button, but I don't think this is an ideal solution (the user then has to go through the confirmation process, which I would ideally would like to prevent)

Comment: STILL A PROBLEM TODAY! I can't stand that the big guys can't work together and realize this use-case is important.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**Update**

The best supported way to prevent automatic sign-in is to use the API method `gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut()` which will prevent automatic sign-in on your site after it has been called.  [Demo here](http://wheresgus.com/stayindemo/).

In the demo, the user is signed out when they leave the page as shown in the following code:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e){
  gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut();
};
```

Now, whenever the user exits the site (e.g. closes the window, navigates away), they will be signed out and the sign in button will not trigger sign-in until the user clicks it.

I don't recommend you do this in your own implementation but instead allow the user to explicitly sign out when they no longer desire want to be signed in. Also, please note that my example is a demo, you probably do not want to sign the user out automatically any time they leave your site.

**Original Post**

First, you should not be using data-approvalprompt="force" as this will cause extra authorized subtokens to be issued to your application / client and is designed to be used in scenarios where the user needs to be reauthorized after credentials have been lost server-side.

Second, you probably do not want to have the behavior where the user needs to click to sign in because they are already "signed in" to their Google account and it could be confusing to need to sign in (or trigger sign-in) again, separately, for your site.

If you really wanted to do this, you would perform an explicit render for the signin button but would not make the call to gapi.signin.render as documented in the [Google+ sign-in documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/) until you are aware that the user will *not* automatically get signed in.

The following code shows how to enable explicit render of the sign-in button:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js">
{"parsetags": "explicit"}
</script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var token = "";
function onSigninCallbackVanilla(authResponse){
   // in a typical flow, you show disconnect here and hide the sign-in button
}
```

The following code shows you how to explicitly render the button:

```
  <span id="signinButton">
    <button id = "shim" onclick="gapi.signin.go(); $('#shim').hide();">Show the button</button>
    <span
      class="g-signin"
      data-callback="onSigninCallbackVanilla"
      data-clientid="YOUR_CLIENT_ID"
      data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
      data-requestvisibleactions="http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity"
      data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login">

    </span>
  </span>
```

How you're communicating that the user is signed out of your site is probably going to vary from site to site, but one approach could be to set a cookie indicating the "signed out" state for a user and then using this as the trigger for blocking explicit load. The behavior gets a little trickier when a user visits your site and has disabled cookies or uses a separate, signed-in, browser. To address this, you could do something complicated like querying the user state from your server over XHR on the sign-in callback and pretending not to know the user is signed in to Google+.

Comment: Can it by anyway change the button's format, look into my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21984213/google-plus-sign-in-in-checkbox

Comment: window.onbeforeunload not working on chrome why so? did you faced the same problem

Comment: Use this if you're using google's new sign in api: ```gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut()```

Comment: Be aware that the `gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut()` call is asynchronous, so you probably want to wrap it in an async function or a promise. If you have follow-up actions to perform that are dependent on it being complete, it gives you some predictability in the sequence. I had an issue with a redirect that I called after `signOut()`, but that would sometimes trigger before the latter was able to finish. As a result, once every few while the next visit to the login page would result in an automatic sign in.

Answer (score 26):

Just check for g-auth-window in the callback function:

```
    function google_sign_callback(authResult){
        if(authResult['g-oauth-window']){

        }else if(authResult['error']) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: I compared the responses but certainly missed 'g-oauth-window'. Thank you!

Comment: Another way is to check `authResult.status.method`.  It will be set to `PROMPT` if the user initiated the request (as opposed to `AUTO`).

Comment: Any idea about the newer API? The closest I see in the current sign-in API is `getAuthResult()` which gives me an object containing tokens and also `session_state: { extraQueryParams: { authuser: '0' } }`

Answer (score 14):

I had this issue and used [auth2.disconnect()](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleauthdisconnect)

```
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
    auth2.disconnect();

    //do other stuff
}
```

Edit:
you need to store the token before you disconnect because in some cases id_token will become null after disconnect:

```
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    var idToken=profile.id_token;
    googleUser.disconnect()

    //use idToken for server side verification
}
```

If i'm correct you have your own sign in mechanism for your site and just need google sign in to sign up a user on verified email. in this case you can easily disconnect after you get the profile info.
Next time you load the page you will see "sign in" button instead of "signed in " button.

Comment: This was super helpful!  I ended up using [`googleUser.disconnect()`](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleuserdisconnect) instead.  The documentation says slightly different things for the two methods, but I'm not sure that they do different things.

Comment: Thanks neal just tested googleUser.disconnect() and did the same

Comment: Anybody know similar solution for facebook?

Comment: Facebook has `FB.logout()` and also you can send an API call to 'disconnect' the user with `FB.api(
            '/me/permissions',
            'delete',
            {},
            function (response) { }
        );`

Comment: Note about this approach: If you're [validating the token](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth#verify-the-integrity-of-the-id-token), it will fail to authenticate because calling `googleUser.disconnect()` expires the token immediately. You'll have to skip the token expiration check on your backend.

Comment: This answer pointed to the right direction for me. The disconnect function solved my problems that I was facing for 3 years on my apps

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately calling `gapi.auth.signOut()` made the app to log-in again when I'm requesting user data (neither it is persistent)

So the solution, as suggested by @class is to revoke the token:

```
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token=' +
        gapi.auth.getToken().access_token,
    async: false,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(result) {
      console.log('revoke response: ' + result);
      $('#authOps').hide();
      $('#profile').empty();
      $('#visiblePeople').empty();
      $('#authResult').empty();
      $('#gConnect').show();
    },
    error: function(e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

I too has same issue this how i fixed it.I may not sure this is a stander way to do it but still it works fine with me...

add this Google JS from google developer

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<script>

function onSuccessG(googleUser) {
        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
        console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
        console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
        console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());
}
function onFailureG(error) {
    console.log(error);
}
function renderGmail() {

  gapi.signin2.render('my-signin2', {
    'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login',
    'width': 0,
    'height': 0,
    'longtitle': true,
    'theme': 'dark',
    'onsuccess': onSuccessG,
    'onfailure': onFailureG
  });
}
```

Now add html link and onClick call this renderGmail() function.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="renderGmail();"> SignUp with Gmail</a>
```

I hope this works...

Comment: We will lose the Google's default sign in button this way.

Comment: and also you then need two clicks to actually log in (if you haven't already 'connected' previously)

Answer (score 3):

I am using https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button to build the sign in button for my web app which gives the user a choice to log in through either Facebook or Google.
This code is pretty easy for obtaining the Id_token. 
However it also came with automatic signing in of the user if the user is already signed in.

Thus, adding the following snippet in the beginning of the script helped me control the signup procedure.

```
    window.onbeforeunload = function(e){
      gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut();
    };
```

Thanks!

Comment: Added in the beginning of which script?

Answer (score 2):

Our AngularJS solution was:

```
$scope.$on('event:google-plus-signin-success', function (event, authResult) {
                if( authResult.status.method !== "AUTO"){
                    onGoogleLogIn(authResult[settings.configKeys.googleResponseToken]);
                }
            });
```

Comment: It is important to note that this answer applies for `google-plus-signin` angular directive. `google-plus-signin-success` is broadcast when signin is successfully done and that includes being logged in in Google account and displaying the Google signin button.

Answer (score 1):

I have been struggling with this for a while and could not find a way to prevent automatic sign in to Google using the "easy implementation" of the Sign-in

I ended up using the [custom integration](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button) which does not attempt to auto sign in (also allowed me to change the appearance in the same time)

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer no longer works when you start to use both Google Sign In and OAuth access tokens for other Google services. The access tokens expire immediately when the user is signed out. Instead, I would recommend the answer from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59429307/how-to-stop-google-logon-onsuccess-from-firering-on-page-load/59431751#59431751), which involves attaching a click event handler to the Google sign in button. Only once the user clicks the sign in button and successfully logs into their Google account will the callbacks events fire.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding a click handler to my Google sign-in button. The click handler sets a global Javascript variable `google_sign_in` to `true`. When the `onSuccess()` handler fires (whether automatically on page load, or manually when the user clicks the sign-in button), it first checks whether `google_sign_in` == `true` and only then does it continue signing the user in:

```
<div id="google-signin2" onclick="return do_click_google_signin();"></div>

<script>
    var google_sign_in = false; // assume

    function do_click_google_signin() {
        google_sign_in = true;
    }

    function onSuccess( googleUser ) {
        if ( google_sign_in ) {
            // Process sign-in
        }
    }

    // Other redundant login stuff not shown...
</script>
```

Comment: You should also set it back to false once the user logs off.