# Google+ sign in and ASP.NET forms authentication, how do I sign out?

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, google-plus

I have an ASP.NET MVC application which uses Google+ sign-in to authenticate the user. The flow is as follows;

1. User accesses controller action decorated with [Authorize]
   attribute, forms authentication is configured so the user is
   forwarded to the log in page.
2. User clicks the Sign In with Google+ button and the server side flow is initiated as per [guide](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow#using_one-time-code_flow)
3. Server receives the Google tokens which are used to authenticate the user, logging them in and returning the standard asp.net auth cookie in the response. The user can then access the site with the cookie.

Now, if I go through the usual asp.net forms log out process of clearing the user's cookie/session there's a problem. If they attempt to access the application after they've logged out but are still signed into a Google product in another tab, they'll be re-directed to my login page. The Google+ sign-in button will automatically sign them back in again initiating the whole sign in process and getting a brand new asp.net cookie!! The only way to truly sign out is to ensure you are not signed into any Google products still and then attempt to sign out. Not exactly user friendly. I guess the same thing happens with all Google products, if I'm signed into Gmail and open Docs, I'll get signed in automagically. The difference being if you sign out of one, you'll sign out of all Google products. I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently not a supported means of logging the user out from your site. What you can do is force the user to click the Google+ Sign-In Button before they will be authorized unless you have set a cookie on their client indicating they are signed in (or enrolled, if you want to distinguish between the sign-in action and being signed-in). You can look at this question:

[how do i sign user out of my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15935770/how-do-i-sign-user-out-of-my-app/15937133#15937133)

or this question:
[Preventing automatic sign-in when using Google+ Sign-In](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15484533/preventing-automatic-sign-in-when-using-google-sign-in/15503280#15503280)

for discussions on this topic on stack overflow and answers to similar questions.