# How to Log User out of an App that uses Google OAuth2 Sign-In?

Tags: python, flask, google-oauth, google-authentication, google-api-python-client

I've implemented a Google OAuth2 login flow in my web-server app (using python/flask). My app redirects the user to Google, where they sign in with Google credentials and get directed back to my app.

**I'm having trouble deciding how to implement the Logout functionality for this app.** I can clear the app's session cookies, but that doesn't log the user out of their Google a/c. So if the user hits Login after logging out, the redirect goes to Google and since the user is still signed into Google, they're automatically (without even being prompted to re-enter credentials) signed back in to my app.

[This SO answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12909332/how-to-logout-of-an-application-where-i-used-oauth2-to-login-with-google) seems to give a good overview of why its *bad practice* to force the user to log out of all Google services. If that's the only way out, I'll do it, but I'm assuming there's a more elegant solution out there?

FWIW, 'revoking' Google access tokens also doesn't work. My app uses the `profile` and `email` scopes for OAuth2 ([see this doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes)). These don't require explicit 'permission-granting' by the user, so there's no such thing as revoking access to these scopes that would force users to be re-prompted at login time.

In case it helps, I used [mostly this doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer) to implement the OAuth2 flow functionality. I could post my code, but (1) It's all in that article, and (2) Unless you're unfamiliar flask/oauth2, it should be irrelevant to answering this question I think.

Any thoughts would be great, thanks.

Comment: In OAuth you don't log people out of the authorization server (Google in your case). How, if, when and how often the authorization server checks the users identify is its own decision. In the end it authorized your application, not the other way around. And it will do so until the user revokes the token for your app. It you invalidate the token on your side, it has no impact on the trust state of the user on the authorization server.

Comment: @KlausD. That's true, and I agree with you. **Therefore, is there _not_ a solution to my problem?** (Other than doing the messy thing suggested at the end of [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12909332/how-to-logout-of-an-application-where-i-used-oauth2-to-login-with-google).)

Comment: How is is *your* problem after all?

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to add `prompt='consent'`. There are different places to add it depending on the API's you are using. Here is one example based on bookshelf app:

```
from oauth2client.contrib.flask_util import UserOAuth2
oauth2 = UserOAuth2()
oauth2.init_app(
    app,
    scopes=['email', 'profile'],
    authorize_callback=_request_user_info,
    client_id=app.config['GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID'],
    client_secret=app.config['GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET'],
    prompt='consent'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can refer the following link to revoke() the token assigned to your App. This will logout user from your app, but he will remain signed into google. Its mentioned on same link you have mentioned in your post above.

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#tokenrevoke

Comment: If you read my question properly you'll see that I've mentioned why revoke() doesn't work, and why I _do need_ to sign the user out of Google but I'm hoping for an elegant way to do so.