# google API firing event even when there is no click (document ready)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-api

I came across in a a very strange bug.
The "Google Sign In" button do his code when the document is ready.
The button do is event when I click on him, But he also do that when the document is ready (and I dont click on him).
My code is this:

```
   <html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Container with the Sign-In button. -->
  <div id="customBtn" class="customGPlusSignIn">
    <span class="icon"></span>
    <span class="buttonText">Google</span>
  </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script');
    po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js?onload=render';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();

  /* render button */
  function render() {
    gapi.signin.render('customBtn', {
      'callback': 'onSignInCallback',
      'clientid': 'my_clientid.apps.googleusercontent.com',
      'cookiepolicy': 'single_host_origin',
      'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'
    });
  }

  function onSignInCallback(resp) {
    gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1', apiClientLoaded);
  }

  function apiClientLoaded() {
    gapi.client.plus.people.get({userId: 'me'}).execute(handleEmailResponse);
  }

  function handleEmailResponse(resp) {
      alert(1);
  }

  </script>

 </body>

</html>
```

In this situation I got the alert(1) when the page is ready. I want to get the alert(1) only when i click on the "google" button.

Thanks to all who read what I wrote :)

EDIT:
You can see the bug in the google demo: https://google-developers.appspot.com/+/demos/signin_email_demo?hl=en

Comment: its because of this `apiClientLoaded`

Comment: If I do not put it in, the code does not work at all. What should be replaced him?

Comment: Where are you firing the event from button click ? I cant see anything like that ..

Comment: This happens automatically when click on the Google button

Comment: Can you try renaming `apiClientLoaded` function call and definition to something else ?

Comment: I tried. it's still working like this.

Comment: Solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15484533/preventing-automatic-sign-in-when-using-google-sign-in