# PHP Google Drive API Integration login and listing files of users

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I have a code it and it is working problem is its only working for 1 person. So if I logged in then it will not show login screen ever again for any user unless that token expires.

index.php

```
<?php

session_start();
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('client_id.json');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);

if (file_exists("credentials.json")) {
  $access_token = (file_get_contents("credentials.json"));
  $client->setAccessToken($access_token);
  //Refresh the token if it's expired.
  if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
    file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
  }
  $drive_service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
  $files_list = $drive_service->files->listFiles(array())->getFiles(); 
  if (count($files_list) == 0) {
    print "No files found.\n";
} else {
    foreach ($files_list as $file) {
        $res['name'] = $file->getName();
        $res['id'] = $file->getId();
        $files[] = $res;
    }
    print_r($files);
}
} else {
  $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/callback.php';
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

So index file checks if credentials.json files has access token or not if exists then list files other wise login user through callback file.

callback.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfigFile('client_id.json');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/callback.php');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE); //::DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY

if (! isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
} else {
  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $access_token = $client->getAccessToken();
  file_put_contents("credentials.json", json_encode($access_token));

  $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/index.php';
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

**This is the wrong approach I guess because it only stores 1 token and shows its value. Is there way that every person who is not logged in needs to login to see his files list.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a button for sign out or create a function that will automatically sign out the user. As stated in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15503280/5995040), you can use `gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut()` to prevent automatic sign-in on your site after it has been called.

You can try his demo [site](http://wheresgus.com/stayindemo/). In the demo, the user is signed out when they leave the page as shown in the following code:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e){
  gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut();
};
```

In his answer in the related post, there are explanation about preventing auto-signin. There are events you can use like window close or navigate away to trigger the sign out method.

Hope this helps.