# How do I get the google account chooser with MVC5 default template

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-mvc-5, owin, google-authentication

The new MVC5 web application templates are pretty nice.  All you need to do is uncomment `UseGoogleAuthentication()`  and you can log in using your google account.  This works fine.

My question is with regards to the login-logout-login cycle. For instance, If I want to test my application with a different google accounts this currently does not work out of the box.

When you log-out it only drops the application cookie but google happily assumes that you want to stay logged-in and when you press google login it will use the account you've previously chosen and skip the account selection process.

As I understand it OWINs `AuthenticationManager.SignOut` is supposed to revoke the external cookie as well as the application cookie but this does not seem to be happening. bug or feature?

I'm aware of the `prompt` parameter (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14384354/force-google-account-chooser)) to force the behaviour however I don't want to force the prompt every time someone hits the app, only when you log-off and back on again.

Any chance for a simple solution? Seems strange that this is not supported.