# Change user with Firebase Google user authentication

Tags: firebase, google-oauth, firebase-authentication

When using Firebase Google user authentication the user is immediately logged in if they have already authorized the application and only logged in to one Google account.

Is there a way to force the "Choose an account" dialog to appear so that the user has the opportunity to login to a different Google account or create a new one?

Currency as far as I know the user has to manually logout of the current Google account (or login to > 1) from Google.com to make the dialog appear.

Answer (score 31):

You can force to choose an account with 'prompt' provider parameter.

```
var googleAuthProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
googleAuthProvider.setCustomParameters({
   prompt: 'select_account'
});
firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(googleAuthProvider)
```

Tested with Firebase JavaScript SDK v4.1.2

Answer (score 3):

You should sign out from Google explicitly:

```
Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(status -> {
    mFirebaseAuth.signOut();
});
```

Found the solution [here](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/187)

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to figure out the same thing. According to some Google documentation, it appears that you can force the account chooser with a "prompt" command (of "none", "select_account" or "consent"):

[Force google account chooser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14384354/force-google-account-chooser)

...however there appears to be no way to set the "prompt" value in any of Firebase's authentication methods (specifically `authWithOAuthRedirect` and `authWithOAuthPopup`).

Were you ever able to figure it out?

Comment: I ended up building my own authentication using [Google Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in), [Firebase Custom Authentication](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/custom.html) and [this node.js oauth proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-firebase-auth-proxy). Not ideal but I couldn't find any other way to do it with Firebase's Google Auth method...

Comment: I contacted Firebase support about this, and they confirmed that there's no way currently to force the Google "Account Chooser" page, but they seemed to think it was a good idea, so perhaps they'll sneak it into a future update.

Answer (score 1):

In my following code, the gooogle sign-in button every time prompts for choosing account...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btn_signOut;
private GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn_signOut = findViewById(R.id.btnSignOut);

    btn_signOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            signOut();
        }
    });

    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
}

private void signOut() {
    mGoogleSignInClient.signOut()
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    finish();
                }
            });

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**Use this way to signout.**

```
 Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(new
 ResultCallback<Status>()
                 {
                     @Override
                    public void onResult(@NonNull Status status)
                     {
                         mAuth.signOut();

                    }

                 });
```

Answer (score 0):

In flutter, use: `GoogleSignIn().signOut();`

(assumming you used the `google_sign_in` package)

Comment: He knows how to `signout()`. Please read more careful questions and then answer.