# After second time login gmail signin do not launches account picker

Tags: ios, gmail-api

I have two account configured in my `Gmail` app. When I launch `Gmail` to sign into my app. It launches account picker. But When I logout and try to sign in again, it automatically selects the previous account without providing me option to choose another.

I am using `gid_signInWithGoogle` of `UIViewController+GIDSignIn` to signin. How can I force Gmail to always provide account picker so that we can switch account after login first time?

Comment: [This question is somewhat relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14384354/force-google-account-chooser). You need to use `select_account` I think, but I don't know how to do it in ios. Maybe you can get some inspiration there at least.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are signing out from Gmail account, using the Gmail SDK method:

```
[[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] signOut];
```

If you doesn't call `signOut` method, then it doesn't allow you to select another account.

Comment: That was helpful. I was missing signout in one scenario.