# Facebook login select account

Tags: facebook-login, facebook-oauth

When implementing Google login into a website, the 'select_account' prompt can be set in order for the user to select a different google account. ([Force google account chooser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14384354/force-google-account-chooser))

Does Facebook offer something similar? I can't seem to find it if they do. The issue I'm running into is if the user selected "Keep me logged in", they can never switch and login with a different Facebook account without going to Facebook and logging out first.