# How to show youtube account selector when click the authorize link - php

Tags: php, youtube-api

I have used youtube google api to get channels from youtube account. When i was click the authorize link it will asks for "account selector" (if more than one channels are found) then the selected channel information is listed.

In next time, i was click the authorize link the account selector, it is not opened.. the previous channel information is listed again..

I want to show the account(channels) selector whenever i will click the authorize link...

please any one help

Answer (score 0):

[OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) give user a choice to pick the channel they want to authorize and give access. Before your app can access private data using a Google API, it must obtain an access token that grants access to that API. Some requests require an authentication step where the user logs in with their Google account. After logging in, the user is asked whether they are willing to grant the permissions that your app is requesting. This process is called `user consent`. It is generally a best practice to request scopes incrementally at the time access is required.

Here's a related SO ticket, it discuss how to show Google account chooser: [Force google account chooser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14384354/force-google-account-chooser)

Comment: thanks for reply... But this is for google login api account selector but i need this same for youtube channel selector...