# Android generating oauth2 token without account chooser

Tags: android, google-app-engine, oauth, google-cloud-endpoints

I am using Google Cloud Endpoints with App Engine, and I have the client library auto-generated for using it. Is there any way for me to implement OAuth2 without "AccountChooser" since I would like to allow my users to sign up anonymously, but still restricting number of hits they can make on the backend.

I could not find any way to generate OAuth2 credentials on Android without AccountChooser. Is there any way at all to do it ? Or I need to risk exposing my APIs to everyone, not just limited users who use my Android APP.

Please help, I am sort of a newbie on OAuth2 & stuff

Comment: This is a big issue since Marshmallow that puts GET_ACCOUNTS as a dangerous permission :(

Comment: OR maybe some way using GCM RegId ? or Firebase ?

Comment: Might the first answer on this question work for you?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14384354/force-google-account-chooser

Comment: Thanks for the Help. Btw I used Firebase for Anonymous as well as Social Registrations. It's pretty smooth.