# When a user is logged into multiple gmail accounts, is there a way to let them select the account they want to use for mailto links?

Tags: javascript, html, email, gmail

When clicking on `mailto` links and selecting Gmail, it opens a stripped-down mail sender UI that a) doesn't make it clear what gmail account you'll be sending from and b) doesn't let you change the account.

You can change it manually in the URL by changing `/u/0` to `/u/1` or setting `authUser`, but is there a way to do this for my users with good UX?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to determine the from address from the "mailto," so maybe advise the users to create a [Chrome profile](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824) for the Work account only, that way when the "mailto" is triggered it will only use that account.

However, if you are programming the "mailto" inside a web app or something, maybe [forcing the Google account chooser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14384354/force-google-account-chooser) from the code even if the user is login will do the trick.

Comment: I think the problem with the chooser is that would only work if they were logging into my site, correct? My site doesn't have accounts. Once they get sent over to gmail I need gmail to force them to choose an account.

Comment: Not really, this is the account chooser that is login to the browser or the web application.